# Is there a best practice for assigning UITabBarController-managed controller properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say you've got a `UIViewController` subclass called `BeverageViewController`, and you are using four separate instances of this controller within a `UITabBarController` collection. You've also got a data structure of, say, four `NSString` string objects, `@"Beer"`, `@"Wine"`, `@"Whiskey"`, and `@"More Whiskey"`. Each string corresponds to one `BeverageViewController` instance, which will use the string for a text label within its view. Hence, when a particular `BeverageViewController` instance is executing its `viewDidLoad` method, it expects to have a public property assigned with with one of these four strings.

When one has such a controller as a segue destination within a `UINavigationController` hierarchy, one typically uses `prepareForSegue:sender:` to set a property of this destination controller before `viewDidLoad` is called.

I've been exploring how to set a controller property before `viewDidLoad`, when the controller is part of a `UITabBarController` collection. I've determined that implementing a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`'s `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method is an ok approach, except you have to dick around to get the relevant tab index of the controller:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    BeverageController *controller = (BeverageController *)viewController;
    controller.beverageName = self.beverageNames[index];
    return YES;
}
```

Don't be fooled: you can't use the `tabBarController.selectedIndex`; you can't use the delegate method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`, because this method fires after `viewDidLoad`. Furthermore, you can't use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex` within the controller's implementation of `viewDidLoad`. These three approaches seem the most obvious, but they do not facilitate the goal above.

Oh lawd, lawd, if only `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` fired before the controller's `viewDidLoad` method. But it doesn't. Nor does it precede `viewWillAppear`, and preparing the view within `viewDidAppear` is, well, moronic.

**What's the best way to set a controller property within a `UITabBarController` collection that enables one to have access to the property within a `viewDidLoad` method, without resorting to abandoning IB and procedurally managing the `UITabBarController`?** Is it my approach above? Is it to implement a custom `UITabBarController` and manipulate the controllers in its `viewControllers` property? Or did I miss the APIobvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your setting everything up in IB and those strings for the `BeverageController` are constant, i.e. they don't change during runtime, you can set them up in IB directly.

In the IB's inspector there is an option called "User Defined Runtime Attributes". If your `BeverageController` subclass has a property called let's say `controllerName`, you just select that VC in IB and click the little plus sign under "User Defined Runtime Attributes", the attribute name would be `controllerName`, then select the string-type and input you value (f.e. "Beer").

If you need to change the values dynamically, your approach with `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` is fine.

Comment: Ah, User Defined Runtime Attributes in the identity inspector, that's the shit.

Answer (score 0):

I use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to set up my viewControllers. Get the tabBarController from your window, and then get each viewController from the tabBarController.

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSAssert([tabBarController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]], @"Must be a tabBarController");

    MBFirstViewController *firstVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
    firstVC.foo = @"Bar";

    MBSecondViewController *secondVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
    secondVC.foo = @"Baz";

    return YES;
}
```